# Can I use "reach" with present

Tags: sequence-of-tenses

> We have walked 1500 meters when we have reached the Eiffel tower

Will it be possible to use *reached* (past simple) or *reach* (present)

If I use past simple for *reach* it will be better to write:

> We walked 1500 meters when we reached the Eiffel tower.

But for *reach* present it seems to be not possible as *reach* express a future something that will be done in a future time

Comment: In future questions, please put your sample sentences in quote boxes, which is done by adding a ">" character at the start of the line of text.

Comment: *We **will have** walked 1500 meters **once we have** reached the Eiffel tower.*

Answer (score 1):

If you're referring to an event that occurred in the past (in other words, you already walked to the Eiffel Tower), you could use the past perfect:

> We **had walked** 1500 meters when we reached the Eiffel Tower.

If you're describing something in the present (in other words, you are currently walking to the Eiffel Tower), you could use the future perfect:

> We **will have walked** 1500 meters when we **reach** the Eiffel Tower.

A possibly more idiomatic expression would be "... by the time we (reached / reach) the Eiffel Tower" and there are other more natural ways to express this, but I think that may be beyond the scope of your question.

---

Your suggested sentence, using the simple past in both clauses, doesn't mean what you might think it means:

> We walked 1500 meters when we reached the Eiffel tower.

This means that you first arrived at the Eiffel tower, and *then* you walked 1500 meters.